# Why would the Children of the Forest create the White Walkers, only to fight them later on?

Tags: game-of-thrones

It is my understanding that the Children of the Forest first created the White Walkers in order to protect themselves from the First Men. However, *something* must have happened that then the Children of the Forest and the First Men teamed up to defeat, or at least repel, the White Walkers. What is that *something*? Or am I misinterpreting the show?